# Is Cache-control: no-store enough to prevent caching?

Tags: web-application, http, caching

I have researched and understood that Cache-Control: no-cache is not sufficient alone to absolutely prevent caching, but what about **Cache-Control: no-store** alone? Since it will not allow storing of cache anywhere, this seems to be enough for preventing caching, is that right? Or is there any catch to that as well?

Comment: I think your question is already addressed in the answer to [Is cache-control: no-cache enough for sensitive information like bank accounts, etc.?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/193032/is-cache-control-no-cache-enough-for-sensitive-information-like-bank-accounts). If you feel that its not sufficiently addresses please point out what's not answered yet. Please also not that all of this is only about *caching*. Your question is not about achieving a specific security requirement, at least you don't show any.

Comment: No, my query is not addressed in that question, though somewhat similar. The answers to that question explain how no-cache is not enough in itself for sensitive information. What I want to know about is, if no-store directive alone is enough? Basically can setting Cache-Control: no-store in response give us a full proof protection if we do not want caching of our responses at all, ever? With reference to https://codeburst.io/demystifying-http-caching-7457c1e4eded no-store means do not store particular resource from the server anywhere (i.e browser or proxy caching )"

Comment: The answer to the linked question explicitly mentions no-store and what can be achieved with this. I don't understand what it is still unknown. And no, `no-store` does not mean to *"not store particular resource from the server __anywhere__"* (and this is also not what you ask), it is only about the cache.

Comment: Yes, I want to know about cache only and also read about what no-store does. My point is if that directive alone sufficient to prevent caching? With reference to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control  "The response may not be stored in any cache. Note that this will not prevent a valid pre-existing cached response being returned. Clients can set max-age=0 to also clear existing cache responses, as this forces the cache to revalidate with the server (no other directives have an effect when used with no-store)."

Comment: What exactly is unclear on what you cite: a) it should not cache it b) it will not make any changes to something which was previously cached (obviously when the header was not set). And this is basically what is said in the linked question: if you don't want to have it stored use no-store. Note that all of this are just instructions of the server. The client or proxy needs to actually follow these instructions properly.

Comment: Simple yes or no answers to - Is 'Cache-Control: no-store' is enough to prevent caching of extremely sensitive information?

Comment: *"Simple yes or no"* - if the client or proxy implements the cache-control as specified, then no-store is sufficient to not store the content in the cache. Of course, if mixed instructions are given (like conflicting cache-control headers in addition to no-store) then it might be not enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I was looking for.